# which database is suitable for Firebase backups?

Tags: json, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I have a Firebase app w/ ~700 MB of data.  I'd like to do some analysis in `javascript` on my computer without chewing-up bandwidth with queries, so I'd prefer to work with the automatic daily database backups Firebase places in `google cloud storage` (which don't cost bandwidth).

Unfortunately, files of that size can be a little unwieldy (esp. in JS, which can't even load a `json` that size w/o streaming parsers).  I can switch to `python`, but what I'd rather do is load it into some kind of small-scale local (or remote, if it's small/cheap) database--something like `sqlite`.

Is there a database that accepts a `Firebase`-esque `json`-style: ie:

```
{
  users: {
    user1: {
       //data
    }
    //...
  },
  documents: {
     doc1: {
       // data
     }
     //....
   }
  //etc
}
```

Most solutions I've found require an `array` of `json` as opposed to one giant `json`.

Less concerned about querying ability and more interested in just being able to access deeply nested data w/ as little boilerplate code as possible.

Comment: This is a pretty vague question: what does your analysis depend on? You mention doing queries. If you migrate your Firebase structure to say, an SQL database, any queries you had previously would not function. If your goal is to simply get the data out of Firebase and into something else, it would be a trivial task to iterate over all of your Firebase nodes and write that data out to any database that can handle a dictionary type object. Couchbase, Realm or sqlite could handle it easily.

Comment: @Jay sorry for vagueness, added a little clarity. the problem w/ `sqlite`/`SQL` is I'd have to do some considerable wrangling of the `firebase` schema to make it reasonable for a regular RDB. It's unfortunately *not* trivial to iterate over the entire database & push it to another database w/o chewing thru bandwidth.  The backup files `firebase` loads into Cloud Storage are perfect for offline analysis, I'm just looking for a reasonable/flexible way to handle a massive `JSON` file.  Most solutions I've found are aimed at arrays of `JSON` documents, not an `object`-style `JSON`.

Comment: It's still pretty confusing. In your question you say you want to work with database backups, perhaps local. To get the data from Firebase to *anything* local is going to require the bandwidth to move the data from one place to another, and again even if you want to work with the Firebase files in Firebase Cloud Storage, you would still need to move the data from there to something local for analysis. Are you perhaps suggesting having your own Firebase server locally where you can work with the data?

Comment: ah, i see the confusion. when I say 'bandwidth,' I mean specifically the bandwidth from `firebase API`, which is billed @ ~$1/GB.  the backups I'm referring to are `gzipped` backups firebase automatically creates each day and places into Google Cloud Storage, which costs a negligible amount to transfer out of. so I already have all of my `firebase` data on my local disk, I'm just trying to figure out how to use it effectively given its weird single-object structure (as opposed to a document collection). I have had some luck with `JSONStream` so far, but not much else.

Comment: That function requires the Blaze plan, which charges for gig stored and then additionally for gig downloaded. If you turn on the backups, I believe you are charged at the standard download rate but because the data can optionally be compressed the fee is less. The structure it saves the data in isn't really weird - it's JSON and pretty easy to convert to a Dictionary ( in Swift 3 it's: myDict = JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: importedData, options: []) as? [String: Any]) ). Once it's in a Dictionary you have a lot of options for massaging the data.